# Power BI - Data Load Error- OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] PostgreSQL: Exception while reading from stream

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, oledb

My question might look similar to some earlier posts but none of the solution has answered what is the rootcause of this behavior.
I would try to explain what I have done so far:

I am connecting to a PostgresDB (running in our company's aws environment) via my Power BI desktop client. The connection set up was pretty easy and I am able to see all the tables in the DB.

For 2 of my table which are extremely big in size, I am trying to load the data I am getting below error message -

**Data Load Error- OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] PostgreSQL: Exception while reading from stream.**

- I tried changing the Command TimeOut Parameter in the initial M
  query-- Didn't help
- I tried writing native query with select * and
  where clause (used parameter)-- It worked

**Question:**
When the Power BI starts loading the data without any parameter, it does start extracting some thousands of record but get interrupted and throws the mentioned error. Is it a limit from the database server side which is getting hit or is it a limitation of power BI?

What can I change in my Database server side, if I don't want to pull information using parameters (as at the end I need all the data for my reports)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, switching from mobile internet to a fixed-line internet worked. Not sure what caused this but just a pointer.